# Tableau - How to have a measure to count success or failure

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am looking to find out how I can create a measure in Tableau that will tell me if a job has been successful or not.

For example I have an agent and I am trying to calculate the number of jobs he worked on and if the completed column has a value of 1 then he successfully completed this otherwise I count it as a failure.

So for this reason I created a calculated field that has the following:

```
IF [Completed]="Y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I then created a new sheet with the number of records for that agent in columns and the measure(above) in rows to create a stacked chart.

The problem I have is that the incompleted tasks are not being counted therefore not reflecting correctly on the chart.

Being new to Tableau I am not sure how to resolve this and would appreciate some advice if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create any calculated field to achieve this. 
Tableau has a built in measure named 'Number Of Records' which has a value of '1' for each record. Assuming your data is this:
[image]

Than you can use it in the chart or table like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jose for your answer. The problem I have is that I would like to create a scatter graph based on the number of success and failures. So in effect with your example I need to have success as the x axis and volume as the y and this can only be achieved with 2 measures rather then dimensions hence the reason I wrote the calculated field.